# Vector Subspace for Differential Equation

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

We are given the following problem:

> Let $S$ be the set of all functions $y$ that satisfy the following differential equation
>   $$2\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}  - 3\dfrac{dy}{dx} + y = 0.$$
>   Show that $S$ is a subspace of the vector space $A$, where $A$ is the set of all functions $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

I do not know how to approach the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show that $S$ is a subspace, you need only to show three things:

- $0\in S$.
- $S$ is closed under addition.
- $S$ is closed under multiplication by a scalar (in fact this shows $0\in S$ if you know $S\neq\emptyset$).

These three points are easily verified, the last two making use of the linearity of the derivative.

Comment: Just a note to OP, if he is given that there exists some element of the vector space in the subspace, he can replace $0 \in S$ with $S \neq \emptyset$. With the other two conditions, these are equivalent. Sometimes that's simpler.